# when exactly does writing in data files occur in sql?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, transactions, rdbms

i am currently studying transaction management in dbms .... from database systems elmasri and navathe 6th edition link: http://mathcomp.uokufa.edu.iq/staff/kbs/file/2/Fundamentals%20of%20Database%20Systems%20-%20Ramez%20Elmasri%20&%20Navathe.pdf

can someone please tell (in short) the transaction commit process i.e. without going into too much detail .... i also read some portion from oracle forum link :
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/transact.htm
what i could understand is that actual writing can take place before or after committing ... but if changes made have to be visible to all users then it must take before commit not after commit , right ?

can someone please help me clear the confusion ??

Comment: You seem to be confusing "writing to a file" with "visible to all users".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the forum post indicates, writes to the data files are completely independent of transaction control.  Changes might be written before a transaction commits, they might be written after the transaction commits.

When changes are made, those changes are made to a version of the data in memory.  In order for a transaction to commit successfully (assuming default commit settings), the change must be written to the redo logs.  That allows the database to re-create the change if it has not been written to data files and the database crashes.  Conversely, if a change is written to a data file before the transaction is committed, information on how to reverse the change will be in the undo logs so that if the transaction will be able to be rolled back if the database fails before the transaction commits (or if the application issues a rollback).

Comment: thank you so much Justin Cave... this is starting to make sense... i just have few doubts more... what about access by other users  ?? if they try to access database before writing of data files and after commit ?? and one more thing that are the undo and redo logs written simultaneously with writing of data in data files ??  are the undo and redo logs also have some of their parts loaded in memory??  ... if so what if the system crashes before writing of log files into memory ...

Comment: @rookie - Other users reading data would read a version of data in memory.  There may be many versions of data in memory none of which are the same as the version of data on disk.  Writes to undo and redo are not synchronous with writes to data files.  Writes to redo have to be written to disk before a transaction can commit.  Writes to data files can happen hours before or days after a commit (though that would be unlikely).